# Окончание в словах

Tags: окончания

На мои просьбы вести себя более сдержанно(ее) и уравновешенно(ее)  реагировала хамством.
Вопрос: как писать окончание в словах сдержанно и уравновешенности.
Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

`вести себя более сдержанно и уравновешенно`

или

`вести себя сдержаннее и уравновешеннее`

Answer (score 0):

Вести себя уравновешенно — так не говорят. Быть уравновешенным — вот так говорят.
И вообще, здесь это неоправданный плеоназм.

**На мои просьбы вести себя более сдержанно [или сдержаннее] реагировала хамством.**

Кстати, "реагировала хамством" тоже плоховато сказано. Надо бы изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Выберем вариант: **На мои просьбы вести себя более сдержанно и уравновешенно реагировала хамством.**

Слова "**сдержанный, уравновешенный, выдержанный**" образуют **синонимический ряд,** при совместном употреблении усиливают значение признака. В то же время форма "сдержаннее и уравновешеннее" неудобна для произношения, хотя в других сочетаниях слово "уравновешеннее" встречается.

**Примеры**

Самым трудным было говорить **медленно и уравновешенно**. [Дина Рубина. Медная шкатулка (сборник) (2015)]

...заискрившись гневом, **договорил с трудом уравновешенно**: ― Очень жаль, что получилось так (Юрий Бондарев).

Он был **гораздо уравновешеннее**, чем брат его Александр Александрович Бестужев-Марлинский: меньше блеска и пылкости, но больше серьезности и глубины. [Л. К. Чуковская. Декабристы (1950-1951)]

Стоит **более уравновешенно** оценивать все поступки людей  [Загадка 11 сентября (2003) // «Спецназ России», 2003.05.15]

Comment: А что значит "неудобна для произношения"? Опять вы выдумываете.

Comment: Это значит, что произносить  подряд два многосложных слова  с двумя гласными на конце неудобно, только и всего. И просьба обойтись без лирических отступлений оценочного характера. Выдумываете в основном ВЫ, так как у Вас нет ни одной ссылки в ответе, всё под честное слово.

Comment: И где вы такое прочитали? Про два многосложных?